# Extjs: click on ascending or decending dropdown

Tags: extjs

Extjs: When i click on ascending or decending dropdown menu, somtimes it gets out of screen or shows only half part. how to avoid it

[image]

Comment: What version of ExtJs? Can you also post a fuller screenshot?

Comment: due to copyright i cant put full screenshot

Comment: Version if copyrighted too? Anyhow, I don't think you will be able to get much help here with so little information

Comment: Ooops sorry, I am using Extjs 4

Comment: Try to recreate your problem in an isolated, simplified example. If it doesn't go away, then post your example on jsFiddle and post a link here.

Comment: It could be other CSS rules interfering, try using firebug or similar to see if any css class is overriding